# PHP killed console app

Tags: php

Hellow, I got a script like this:

```
$worker      = new WordWorker($someFile);
$changedFile = $worker->replace()->save();
```

The script handles a word file, when file size more than 1.5 Mb and when I run script with console, I get:

> /usr/local/bin/php: line 6: 45771 Killed
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/jails/php54_2/lib:/usr/jails/php54_2/usr/local/lib
>   /usr/jails/php54_2/usr/local/bin/php -c
>   /usr/jails/php54_2/usr/local/etc/php-cli.ini -d
>   extension_dir=/usr/jails/php54_2/usr/local/lib/php/extension_dir -d
>   zend_extension=/usr/jails/php54_2/usr/local/lib/php/extension_dir/ioncube/ioncube_loader_fre.so
>   "./yii" "order-queue/execute-orders"

Any `set_time_limit` or `ini_set('memory_limit')` cant help me. At least, when I start the script from browser everything is ok.

Comment: i'm using Yii2 and cant find nothing in his logs, no exception or something like this

Comment: And in web server logs?

Comment: Sounds like some "security" module interventing

Comment: Are you trying to execute this on a shared server? They probably don't like long-running scripts. Judging from the `/jails/` file path it's specifically set up that way.

Comment: Yep its shared now, but why script runnig from http request?
btw soon i'm transfer this project to own server, think problem will be solved?

Comment: Web serverver logs nothing too